# Grabbing Specific Value from JSON Data API

Tags: python, json

I am fully aware there are other topics on this on this website, but the solutions do not work for me.

I am trying to grab the 'last' value from this API address:
https://cryptohub.online/api/market/ticker/PLSR/

In Python, I have tried many different scripts, and tried hard myself but I always end up getting a "KeyError" although "last" is in the API. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please add source code. Also what python version - 2 or 3?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/jKmMPS6S -- source code (Python 3.6.4, latest)

Comment: try `response.json()['BTC_PLSR']['id']` for `id`, and `response.json()['BTC_PLSR']['last']` for `last` value.

Comment: I keep getting a TypeError: object is not subscriptable. ('int object is not subscriptable, and 'float' object is not subscriptable) [Edit: Nevermind, viewed answer]

Comment: check my answer, just tested my statements and everything works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data in response has structure:

```
$ curl  https://cryptohub.online/api/market/ticker/PLSR/ | json_pp
{
   "BTC_PLSR" : {
      "baseVolume" : 0.00772783,
      "lowestAsk" : 0.00019999,
      "percentChange" : -0.0703703704,
      "quoteVolume" : 83.77319071,
      "last" : 0.000251,
      "id" : 78,
      "highestBid" : 5e-05,
      "high24hr" : 0.000251,
      "low24hr" : 1.353e-05,
      "isFrozen" : "0"
   }
}
```

i.e. dictionary inside dictionary, so to extract values you need:

```
data = response.json()["BTC_PLSR"]
visitors = data["id"]
```

**UPDATE on comment:**

Im not sure I understand you, I did a simple test and it works fine:

```
$ python3 << EOF
> import requests
> url = 'https://cryptohub.online/api/market/ticker/PLSR/'
> response = requests.get(url)
> data = response.json()['BTC_PLSR']
> print('ID ==> ', data['id'])
> EOF
ID ==>  78
```

As you can see line `print('ID ==> ', data['id'])` returns output `ID ==>  78`

**Test source code:**

```
import requests
url = 'https://cryptohub.online/api/market/ticker/PLSR/'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()['BTC_PLSR']
print('ID ==> ', data['id'])
```

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful, however, although it fixes the problem, it doesn't display anything in the console. It just simply says: Visitor:    Then it's blank. Why would this be? Sorry to pester.

Comment: Okay, NO IDEA why it didn't work for me, but I got it working when just removing a bunch of my previous code, anyway, its solved, THANK YOU! So sorry for pestering again!